# Agena Bayesian Network Gives a Node Error

Tags: r

I am using agena.ai to explore Bayesian Networks.  After installing everything and trying the first lines of code.

```
library(agena.ai)

#First we create the "mean" and "variance" nodes

mean <- Node$new(id = "mean", simulated = TRUE)
```

I have the following error

```
Error: object 'Node' not found
```

Can anyone help me get past this hurdle?

Comment: Yes, the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/agena.ai/readme/README.html) isn't very clear how to create the initial `Node` object (there is also the same lack of clarity for Model, Network objects etc). Might be worth sending an email to `maintainer("agena.ai")` :  "Eugene Dementiev <support@agenarisk.com>" for details ... as not sure how many will have a licence for this software.

Comment: Just playing about with it ... `Node = new("Node", id = "node_one"); Node`  amd `node_four = new("Node",id = "node_four", type = "Ranked", states = c("Very low", "Low", "Medium", "High", "Very high")) ; node_four$probabilities` seems to be setting things up ... but this is not how it is documented

Comment: ok, two excellent answers from @user20650 ... I will contact the support and think about closing out the question with a fuller answer with examples.  Noting that the 2nd answer above ^ has fulfilled the criteria of the original question; that is, it has got me over the first hurdle.

Answer (score 1):

This answer comes from @user20650.  Attempting to work through the example given in this [github entry](https://github.com/AgenaRisk/api-r#101-diet-experiment-model) it was found that the code threw the error shown in the original question.  Further, the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/agena.ai/readme/README.html) wasn't forthcoming.

```
library(agena.ai)

#First we create the "mean" and "variance" nodes

mean <- Node$new(id = "mean", simulated = TRUE)
mean$set_expressions("Normal(0.0,100000.0)")

variance <- Node$new(id = "variance", simulated = TRUE)
variance$set_expressions("Uniform(0.0,50.0)")
```

However, following the suggestion from @user20650,

```
Node = new("Node", id = "node_one")
```

the following code was found to work (ie not throw an error),

```
library(agena.ai)

#First we create the "mean" and "variance" nodes

mean <- new("Node", id = "mean", simulated = TRUE)
mean$set_expressions("Normal(0.0,100000.0)")

variance <- new("Node", id = "variance", simulated = TRUE)
variance$set_expressions("Uniform(0.0,50.0)")
```

and also (as suggested earlier) the maintainer of the documentation will be informed.

Comment: btw just noticed that `agena.ai:::Node$new(id = "node_one")` *works*, so this just might be an issue with exporting / namespace ... i've not looked